Did the new on-demand electric boat taxi service developed by the BMA launch in Bangkok in July 2024, and if not what's the new scheduled launch date?
I read on https://www.bangkokpost.com/thailand/general/2807829/new-city-boat-service-set-to-start-in-july:

An on-demand electric boat taxi service developed by the Bangkok Metropolitan Administration (BMA) is due to begin operating in July, around the time the BMA looks set to launch the city-wide expansion of its app-based motorcycle taxi-hailing service, Krung Thep Thanakom Co (KT), the BMA’s business arm, revealed on Sunday.

Did this on-demand electric boat taxi service developed by the Bangkok Metropolitan Administration (BMA) launch in July 2024, and if not, what's the new scheduled launch date?

Reddit user oonnnn pointed me to https://siamrath.co.th/n/555505:

It is expected that the taxi boat service will officially begin by the end of this year. [via Google Translate]

They forgot to check if there is enough water in the canals for the boats:

Currently, the BMA has prepared 2 improved electric boats and is in the process of selecting the pilot canal routes. The problem found is that various canals in Bangkok are used to drain water, causing unstable water levels, which can be an obstacle to boats. For example, there are about 3-4 months a year when the water level in the canals must be very low. [via Google Translate]

